# Should I fear cows? How can I encourage them to let me pass?

Tags: mountain-bike, trails, animals

Recently a herd of cows appeared at my local trail. They often block the trail. I, being a city boy, don't know how to respond. I don't feel comfortable yelling at a creature which could easily break half of my bones with a single shot. This is especially true when there are little calves with their moms present. What is the right way to politely ask cows to move over?

Comment: The main problem is that the cows may not readily get out of your way.  Shouting at them from a respectable distance may cause them to move, or they may just look at you and stand there.

Comment: @DanielRHicks and what exactly should one shout at a cow?    `mooooooove !`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In short: You don't have to fear cows, but a healthy dose of respect is appropriate.

Normally cow herds aren't really aggressive. Therefore, it's quite safe to just go around the herd (if it's blocking the trail), or pass the herd if it's close to the trail. Going right through the herd is unwise unless you know what you're doing.

Additional caution is advised when encountering:

- **mother cows**, which always want to protect their calves,
- and/or **bulls**, which can be somewhat aggressive.

If either of the above situations are present, keep your distance. Consider leaving extra space between you and the herd, so as not to get too close. Depending on the size of their meadow, it may be easiest to just avoid their meadow altogether, or at least stay 50 to 100 meters away.

Comment: I've heard that some species are particularly violent, so you may want to gather some details on the one you'll visit.

Comment: Wild or feral cows are quite a different animal to domesticated cows. Bulls -always respect and give  wide berth no matter what.  Have no fear of a dairy cows, even one with a calf will not see you as a threat - don't scare them with surprises, sudden movement and noisy brakes and you will be right. Make enough noise so they know you are there though.

Comment: Be aware that not all cows are the same. Meat breeds which are allowed to roam free in more demanding terrain are generally more skittish and aggressive then more domestic breeds. The Longhorn half-breeds I dodged in my youth were not nice animals, though the cows would not follow through once they had you running. A bull--if you were unlucky and unwary enough to encounter one--was a real threat.

Comment: How would one tell the difference between meat or dairy cows while out on the trail alone?

Comment: @user29020: If you cannot tell the difference, you should stay well clear of all cattle, as you might also struggle to to tell the difference between a cow and a bull.

Comment: The answer by PeteH has a link that clearly shows aggression is often linked to Dogs being close by. Be more wary if there are Dogs around.

Comment: I don't think that we have meat breeds here in Israel, because most of our meat comes from Argentine, on the other hand we hold the record for liters of milk per cow :) I choose your answer because of well explained cases that should draw my attention.

Answer (score 10):

Something that has not been mentioned so far. Be aware of the **herding dog**. In the area where I bike (South Italy), herds are usually left with a couple of herding dogs by the shepherd. The only bad experience I had with a herd was not with cows itself, but with a dog. Since then, I pass through if there is no dog, or I wait/turn around if there is a herding dog.

Comment: Shepherd dogs for *cows*...?

Comment: @gerrit Yes, they have such sometimes but mostly not to keep the herd together but more to prevent the cattle from being stolen. Therefore those dogs are quite aggressive against strangers approaching "their" herd. They are trained to be left alone with the cattle over several weeks and you can just give them a bunch of food which they manage to distribute over this time by themselves.

Comment: Exactly what @BenediktBauer said: the dogs (usually a couple) are there to avoid that the cattle is stolen, so they're trained to be aggressive. I know leaving the dogs there is a terrible habit, and I don't even know if it's legal.

Answer (score 8):

When I read your question I had a vague recollection of reading something not so long ago about this. Have a look at this article from a UK newspaper (check out also the related articles on the page):

[Cow Attacks](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/earth/countryside/10064225/Cow-attacks-It-looked-like-they-wanted-to-kill-him.html)

So you are absolutely right to be cautious - people have been killed by cows.

Personally, I live in a rural area (the New Forest in southern UK - ponies, cattle, donkeys and even pigs roam pretty much freely) and have done a bit of walking myself. I've never seen what you might call aggression, but cows can get boisterous especially, for example, if they think you're bringing them food.

Bearing in mind that a cow could weigh several hundred kilos or more, if one were to bump into you, even if not particularly intentionally, you'd certainly know about it. The article is right in that when we see them at a distance we think nothing of it, but meet them close up - they are enormous and you can quite easily imagine how people get trampled and crushed.

Now, as regards what you *should* do, I think you probably need to play every scenario by ear, but most of the time they won't be interested in you so as long as you proceed with caution and give them as wide a berth as possible you should be fine. Don't necessarily expect them to move for you, it'll probably be you who needs to take action to avoid them, but you should be fine.

Comment: Similar stories and more details at https://www.google.com/search?q=killed+by+cows

Comment: +1 for reference. Common theme mentioned in the article is most attacks involve a Dog being present. Dogs attach cows, cows (particularly with Calf) will attack them, and people around them.

Comment: @mattnz yes that's totally understandable about dogs. But I've also been walking through a field (no dogs) when a cow got quite excited (no apparent malice) and came trotting toward me. It was quite scary, hoping she didn't actually hit me. I think she must have thought I was the farmer. Whether or not any of this could happen while on a bike I don't know, but I wouldn't discount it.

Answer (score 4):

In Switzerland, "normal cows" (milking cows with no calfs and no bulls) are generally not seen as dangerous. I passed them many times from very close distance. Of course, you should not touch them or anything the like and do not squeeze between them so that they could push you to the ground and then step on your bicycle (that might injure also them, then I already do not know). [See here](https://swissfamilyfun.com/hiking-safely-with-cows/) about Swiss cows.

Still, if a cow attacks seriously enough to bring you to the hospital, you are likely to stay there for 4.5 days in average and the mortality rate is 3 %. The cow most likely will try a headbutt (36%), closely followed by the kick (35%) and then physical contact (20%) or trampling (12%) ([source](https://smw.ch/index.php/smw/article/view/3229)).

Cows with calves may attack: mama cows are very protective and may charge anything they see as a threat. Accidents do happen. The danger is, calves grow fast and may just look like "smaller cows" rather than "babies" so you may not be that quickly aware of.

Bulls are uncommon in these days but they generally may attack without obvious reason so pass over large distance with great respect.

Answer (score 2):

As a bit of a farm boy. Cows are normally pretty docile, generally if you just let them know you're there and are calm, they will also be calm.  Get in their eye line so they can see you approaching, and they will in most cases move out of the way on their own accord.

Of course, there are exceptions, so it is a good idea to show a healthy amount of respect and be prepared to turn tail and bolt

Answer (score 1):

The best way to safely pass cows on a bicycle is to slow down, approach them carefully, and try to pass them without startling them. You can also let them know you're there by saying "Sorry cow, I'm just passing by" in a friendly tone. Also, if there are farms or landowners nearby, you can enlist their help in moving the cows safely through the area.
Another thing to pay attention to is not to wear red cycling clothes, that's all. I am more afraid of running into dogs than cattle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I can't tell if this intended to be a joke or not.  I don't think it _matters_ what you say to a cow, since I question its ability to understand.  And cows are also dichromats, and only see blue and yellow, so red means nothing to them.

Comment: Animals may understand the intonation